# How to filter records in mongodb in spring boot application?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

## Problem

I need to filter records based on certain parameters(X,Y,Z,A,B) in mongodb db and spring boot.

## Things I have done -->

1)I have used queries like
a)findByXOrYorAorB

The problem with this is in the case when I receive 2 records from user and when I apply findByXOrYorAorB.I get those records also that have null values for them in db apart from those matching A and B.

b)findByXNotNullOrYNotNullorANotNullorBNotNull

The problem with this is in the case when I receive 2 records from user and when I apply findByXNotNullOrYNotNullorANotNullorBNotNull.I get those records also that have not null values(i.e any xyz value) for them in db apart from those matching A and B.

Another Problem for this are if the search params increase so does by findByX queries.

I am new in using spring data mongo db.

> Can any one guide me how to filter records?

Comment: Are you using spring data mongodb

Comment: couple of options. 1. QueryDsl 2. Create custom respository implementation

Comment: @AjitSoman Yes using One of its interface MongoRepository

Comment: @pvpkiran Thankx Can you share the example so that it is helpful

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-data/spring-data-add-custom-method-to-repository/

Comment: @pvpkiran is this example efficient way to do that if I have 8 or 9 params to filter.